# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected in SeleniumWebDriver

Tags: java, oracle, selenium-webdriver

I created a class (ValidarStatusOsPage) in java that makes a connection to the DB and returns to a test class (ValidateStatusOsTest) the result of the query and prints to the screen.

When I run the test class, the Eclipse console displays the message:

**ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expecte**

I have reviewed the code several times but I can not verify where the error is.

Below is the Java class for connecting to the DB and the test class.

```
public class ValidarStatusOsTest {

static String query;

@Test
public void validarOs() {

    ValidarStatusOsPage os = new ValidarStatusOsPage();
    query = os.returnDb("179195454");

}}


public class ValidarStatusOsPage {

String resultado;

public String returnDb(String NuOs) {
    // Connection URL Syntax: "jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:portnumber/db_name"
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.5.12.116:1521:desenv01";

    // Database Username
    String username = "bkofficeadm";

    // Database Password
    String password = "bkofficeadmdesenv01";

    // Query to Execute
    String query = "SELECT NU_OS, CD_ESTRATEGIA, CD_STATUS, NU_MATR, DT_ABERTURA" +
                   "FROM tb_bkoffice_os"+
                   "WHERE  NU_OS ="+ NuOs +"";

    try {
        // Load mysql jdbc driver
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        // Create Connection to DB
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);

        // Create Statement Object
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        // Execute the SQL Query. Store results in ResultSet
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        // While Loop to iterate through all data and print results
        while (rs.next()) {
            String NU_OS         = rs.getString(1);
            String CD_ESTRATEGIA = rs.getString(2);
            String CD_STATUS     = rs.getString(3);
            String NU_MATR       = rs.getString(4);
            String DT_ABERTURA   = rs.getString(5);

            resultado = NU_OS + "  " + CD_ESTRATEGIA + "  " + CD_STATUS + "  " + NU_MATR + "  " + DT_ABERTURA + "\n";
            System.out.println(NU_OS + " - " + CD_ESTRATEGIA + " - " + CD_STATUS + " - " + NU_MATR + " - "+ DT_ABERTURA);

        }
        // closing DB Connection
        con.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return resultado;
}}
```

[image: ORA-00923Erro]

Comment: make some spaces in the end please

Comment: You muss a blank before FROM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 points are there in your query:

```
SELECT NU_OS, CD_ESTRATEGIA, CD_STATUS, NU_MATR, DT_ABERTURA" +
               "FROM tb_bkoffice_os"+
               "WHERE  NU_OS ="+ NuOs +""
```

1. space before FROM missed first part of query is: `SELECT NU_OS, CD_ESTRATEGIA, CD_STATUS, NU_MATR, DT_ABERTURAFROM`
2. space missed before WHERE: `SELECT NU_OS, CD_ESTRATEGIA, CD_STATUS, NU_MATR, DT_ABERTURAFROM tb_bkoffice_osWHERE  NU_OS =`
3. concatenate parameter into SQL string is exact hack point for SQL Injection attack. Never do it in real program even if it is pure standalone. Always use parameters for queries.

and a little last one: `+ NuOs +""` - last "" has no sense at all...

good luck.

UPD: @YCF_L absolutely right use Prepared statement.

you need to do this:
in Sql String:            `WHERE  NU_OS = ?`

in code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

stmt.setString(1, NuOs); 
 //also works: stmt.setObject(1,NuOs);
```

things to remember with JDBC:

1. all parameters in SQL are just ? marks
2. parameter indexes start with 1 (not 0)
3. and in order they appear in SQL from strat to end

(e.g. `Select * FROM tbl WHERE col1=? and col2=?`
 has parameter 1 for col1 and parameter 2 for col2

PS. your initial SQL has one more error but I'm not going to tell you what is it :-)  use parameter and all be fine.

Comment: Vadim, What would be the correct way to avoid a hack attack. Do you have an example of the right way?
I'm a beginner in programming.

Comment: @Kakashi-Sensei by using [Prepared Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)